# How to do a simple file search in cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

I want to quickly search for a file given its name or part of its name, from the windows command line (not power shell). This is similar to opening explorer and using the search box at the top.

Note: `dir` can search based on a string template but it will not search in the subdirectories.

Note2: `findstr` can be used to search for a token inside files and has a recursivity flag; it's funny that a more complex find can be easily discovered ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/177234/can-i-use-cmd-to-search-for-files-in-windows

Answer (score 294, accepted):

`dir /s *foo*` searches in current folder and sub folders.

It finds directories as well as files.

where /s means[(documentation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir):

> /s    Lists every occurrence of the specified file name within the
> specified directory and all subdirectories.

Comment: I have another question, how to copy these found documents to another folder? THanks a lot

Comment: @HongCheng You can use **wildcard** with `Xcopy` after verifying the output with the `DIR` command above as use the same as `xcopy *foo* c:\Temp` to find all the `*foo*` files and  copy them in `c:\Temp` directory

Comment: This refuses to find files I know are present within a subfolder of the current directory.  Navigating to that folder and searching produces the result, but it is not found when searching via a parent directory.  Is there any other more robust command?

Comment: @JoeDimig Probably it is a system or hidden file, for that you can use `dir /a:h /s /b` or `dir /a:s /s /b` for more reference plz see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25717502/3057246

Answer (score 187):

Please try the following commands

**List all files in the current directory & subdirectories**

```
dir /b/s *.txt
```

The above command searches for all txt file in the directory tree.

> But as windows is started naming directories as `.nuget`,`.vscode` it also comes with the command above.

In order to avoid this and have a clean list use `/a:-d` filter as

```
dir /a:-d /b/s
```

Before using it just change the directory to **root** using

```
cd/
```

There is one more hacky command to do the same

```
for /r %f in (*) do @echo %f
```

> **Note:** If you miss the `@echo` part in the command above it will try to execute all the files in the directories, and the `/r` is what making it recursive to look deep down to subdirectories.

---

**Export result to text file**

you can also export the list to a text file  using

```
dir /b/s *.exe >> filelist.txt
```

and search within using

```
type filelist.txt | find /n "filename"
```

---

If you are looking for files with special attributes, you can try

**List all Hidden Files**

```
dir /a:h-d /b/s
```

**List all System Files**

```
dir /a:s-d /b/s
```

**List all ReadOnly Files**

```
dir /a:r-d /b/s
```

**List all Non Indexed Files**

```
dir /a:i-d /b/s
```

If you remove the `-d` from all commands above it will list directories too.

---

**Using `where` in windows7+:**

Although this **dir** command  works since the old dos days but Win7 added something new called **Where**

```
where /r c:\Windows *.exe *.dll
```

will search for **exe** & **dll** in the drive **c:\Windows** as suggested by @SPottuit you can also copy the output to the clipboard with

```
where /r c:\Windows *.exe |clip
```

just wait for the prompt to return and don't copy anything until then.

**Page break with `more`**

If you are searching recursively and the output is big you can always use `more` to enable paging, it will show `-- More --` at the bottom and will scroll to the next page once you press `SPACE` or moves line by line on pressing `ENTER`

```
where /r c:\Windows *.exe |more
```

For more help try

```
where/?
```

Comment: You can also export the list to your clipboard by replacing `>> filelist.txt` with `| clip`. [More info about using | clip](http://www.labnol.org/software/copy-command-output-to-clipboard/2506/).

Comment: By adding `/b` behind `dir` only the filename or filepath(if searching in multiple folders) is returned(**b**are format) and no details of the file and folder. By adding `/s` behind `dir` the **s**ub-directories will also be searched. [More info about the dir command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755121.aspx).

Comment: Don't know why this isn't the accepted answer. Contains everything that has and a lot more. Thanks for posting this. Wish I could upvote more than once!

Comment: What if I can't change the directory? I have an E: drive and I can't change to it with CD.

Comment: ? even in drive E if you type cd\ it will take you to the root, i have updated the answer for your reference

Comment: one would expect that only cd\ or cd \ would change to the root directory, but it seems cd/ also does the job on Windows 10 - not sure since what DOS/Windows version this is true though

Comment: btw, an answer https://superuser.com/questions/177234/can-i-use-cmd-to-search-for-files-in-windows also mentions using the FOR command for filtering results

Comment: something that may be helpful with CD is the CD /D someFullPath which also changes the current drive and the CD %HOMEDRIVE% which changes to the home drive (https://support.microsoft.com/el-gr/help/101507/how-windows-nt-determines-a-user-s-home-directory). e.g. you can use CD /D %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% to set user's home folder as the current folder

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis Yes, one can explore lot of things like using wildcard as cd Win*\\*32 , but it's out of context

Comment: @Vinod Srivastav, very nice. All possible scenarios explained.

Answer (score 2):

`dir *.txt /s /p`
will give more detailed information.

Comment: What details ? `/p` will pause and it's same as `where /r c:\Windows *.exe /T |more`

Answer (score 0):

Problem with DIR is that it will return wrong answers.
If you are looking for DOC in a folder by using `DIR *.DOC` it will also give you the **DOCX**. Searching for `*.HTM` will also give the **HTML** and so on...

Comment: That's why one should use *WHERE* as `Where /R c:\ *.DOC *.HTM` for the purpose

Comment: Vinod Srivastav. I tried it now and wow, this work wonders. :)
I will implement this to my batches.

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching any file or directory with name example

Use

```
dir example /s /p
```

Answer (score -1):

You can search in windows by DOS and explorer GUI.

DOS:

1) DIR

2) ICACLS (searches for files and folders to set ACL on them)

3) cacls   ..................................................

2) example

icacls c:*ntoskrnl*.* /grant system:(f) /c /t ,then use PMON from sysinternals
to monitor what folders are denied accesss.
The result contains

access path contains your drive

process name is explorer.exe

those were filters youu must apply

Comment: Please try improve your answer. The original question is tagged with `windows` & `cmd` not with `sysinternals/pmon`. There are other ways like using the `FindFirstFileA` in a **C program** or to use `Directory.GetFiles` in a **c# program** but they are out of the context.