# Laravel Views - Possible caching issue

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to test a laravel upgrade on our production server.

I created a new vhost and copied the entire directory over of the original laravel app to the new vhost root.

So I have app.mydomain.com with the original (laravel 5.8 app) and l6.mydomain.com with the copied version.

My issue is that if I make any changes to the views on l6.mydomain.com I can't see any change yet if I make changes to the views on app.mydomain.com the updates are visible on both...

I assumed I'd made an error in the vhost file and was looking at the same installation on both domains but it looks correct and in fact any changes to the Controllers or other PHP files works fine it is just the views that are being replicated across both.

Sorry it's a bit of a convoluted question but any help much appreciated.

Comment: Check some cache folders. Most likely dynamically generated code still has absolute URL to old location

Comment: thanks, that sounds about right, but I've tried `php artisan cache:clear` `php artisan view:clear` and `rm -rf storage/framework/cache/*` and the problem still seems to persists... any where else I could clear / check?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-do-i-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux

or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066679/how-to-do-a-simple-file-search-in-cmd

I don't use Laravel, just guessing. Maybe some config?

Comment: hmn, yeah, good idea

Comment: deleted everything with a reference to the url but still same issue... quite intrigued now as to how this is happenning... thanks for the ideas though

Comment: @Justinas, yep you were right it was in bootstrap/cache/config.php - a full cache of the config file with absolute paths... not sure how i missed that earlier. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel holds a cache of the config file at `bootstrap/cache/config.php`. This can be cleared with `php artisan config:clear` as explained in better detail here: [how to clean Laravel Bootstrap cache config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33823207/how-to-clean-laravel-bootstrap-cache-config-file/51745043).