# Find all directories by specific name recursively and write full paths into a text file

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line

I would like to be able to search for specific directory with specific name and save their paths into a text file. for example, for a directory titled `abc` in parition `c:\`

I would like to search for all of its occurances of ‘abc’ in ‘c:\’ and save the paths of the occurrences into a text file titled `paths.txt`.

Example:

```
C:.
├───aaa
│   └───aab
├───abc
│   └───grumble
└───whatever
    └───abc
        ├───abc
        └───pla
```

I want to get a text file containing:

```
C:\abc
C:\whatever\abc
C:\whatever\abc\abc
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to combine several things to do this. The `dir` command is able to search recursively, show things attributed as directorys and use a plain display format - here are the relevant switches (to see more, use `dir /?`):

```
DIR [drive:][path][filename] [/A[[:]attributes]] [/B] [/S]
or
DIR [/A[[:]attributes]] [/B] [/S] [drive:][path][filename]

  [drive:][path][filename]
          Identifies drive, directory and/or files.
  /A      Lists files with specified attributes.
  Attribute D directories
  /S      Lists files and all subdirectories.
  /B      Simple format (no header, no summary).
```

You can pipe the result in a file using this syntax:   `dir /AD /S /B  abc > somefile.txt` - `abc` is the directory name - you can also use wildcards like
`dir /AD /S /B  *abc* > somefile.txt` to find any directory that contains `abc`.

Using `dir *abc* /AD /S /B > somefile.txt` works the same - position of it does not seem to matter.

See

- [How to do a simple file search in cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066679/how-to-do-a-simple-file-search-in-cmd) for some more explanation and slightly different usecase.
- [How to redirect Windows cmd stdout and stderr to a single file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420965/how-to-redirect-windows-cmd-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-single-file) for more compley piping of stdout/stderr to file.